# Local storage value clears on refresh

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a function which draws a graph from the 7 values selected by the user. It works fine, but the local storage values set for each of the variable dissapears on a refresh

```
function drawChart() {
      

 var dates = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
    var days;
    for(days=1;days<=dates;days++)
    {
        document.write(days);
    }



const coordinates2 = dates;
      
const[one,two,three,four,five,six,seven
 

]= coordinates2.split(',')




localStorage.setItem('one',one); // storing is successful but clears on refresh



// i have also tired Json.stringify but it did not good

localStorage.setItem('one', JSON.stringify(one)); //storing is successful but clears on refresh

}
```

I can see that the browser is storing the variable value, and it disappears as soon as the browser refreshes. Is there something else i need to do. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the value is already set before you set it

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('one')){
localStorage.setItem('one',one);
}
```

Comment: Hey this works, but only saves the first value the user puts. Its does not overwrite the new selected values,

Comment: I see. In your original solution, was the value being cleared by the call to localstorage.setItem()? Could you just write a check to make sure one is only being set when it has a legit value?